# In R, I have 10 fixed width text files split into 8 parts. How can I pull in the 80 files, separate into their respective files and combine the parts?

Tags: r, for-loop, fixed-width, file-import

So I have 80 files that come in the file name format:

```
P.A3588.ACO.CCLF0.ROW1.ROW30000
P.A3588.ACO.CCLF1.ROW1.ROW30000
P.A3588.ACO.CCLF0.ROW30001.ROW60000
```

There are 80 fixed width text files: 8 parts for each of the 10 CCLF numbers (CCLF0,CCLF1,...,CCLF9). I want to be able to group by CCLF number, apply the column width vector, and bind the rows of the CCLF parts.

Below is what I've tried so far. It doesn't work, but gives an idea what I'm attempting.

```
filenames <- list.files(dataPath)
names <- substr(filenames,13,17)

CCLF1_width <- c(13,6,11,2,10,10,1,1,7,7,2,17,1,2,2,4,1,10,10,10,10,10,2,10,10,10,11,2,2,1,1,1)
CCLF2_width <- c(13,10,11,2,10,10,4,10,5,11,6,10,10,24,17,2,2,2,2,2)
CCLF3_width <- c(13,11,2,2,7,10,11,6,10,10,1)
CCLF4_width <- c(13,11,2,1,2,7,11,6,10,10,7,1)
CCLF5_width <- c(13,10,11,2,10,10,3,2,2,1,2,10,10,5,15,1,7,10,10,2,2,2,10,10,40,11,17,24,2,2,2,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,1)
CCLF6_width <- c(13,10,11,2,10,10,1,2,10,10,5,15,1,10,10,2,2,2,10,10,40,11,17,2)
CCLF7_width <- c(13,11,11,2,10,2,20,1,1,24,9,2,20,13,2,10,10,12,9)
CCLF8_width <- c(11,2,3,5,10,1,1,3,2,2,10,10,10,30,15,40,1,1)
CCLF9_width <- c(11,11,10,10,12)
CCLF0_width <- c(11,11)

for (i in length(filenames)){
  assign(paste0(substr(filenames,13,17)), read_fwf(grepl("CCLF1",filenames),paste0(i,"_width")))
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. `558asd.MBP.FILE0.ROW1.ROW30000` is that the *filename* format or some format for the *content* of the file? For reading fixed width data you can use `read.fwf`. I don't know what you mean by *"I want to be able to pull them all in"*. Pulling as in reading? Downloading? Or perhaps you mean pooling as in combining/merging?

Comment: The `purrr` package is great for making this sort of task easier, taking care of the looping for you. It also allows for error handling, so it can skip problematic files rather than grinding to a halt.    https://www.hvitfeldt.me/2018/01/purrr-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: @MauritsEvers, Yes, that's the file name. I want to pull in all 80 txt files and separate them in to 10 distinct data frames based on the file number.

So all the parts of File0 should be in a data frame called File0, all the parts of File1 will be in a data frame called File2, etc.

Comment: @divibisan. I'm trying to put them in multiple dataframes. There's 8 files with File1 in the file name, 8 Files with File2, etc to File9. The first part of the file name is static, but the latter vary by row numbers.

Each File1,...,File9 is a fixed width text file with different column widths.

Comment: I edited the post for clarity.

Comment: What is your goal in your for loop? The first argument in `read_fwf` should be file path.

Comment: I've tried going down the road of using R to parse CCLF files from CMS. It works fine when your ACO is small- but as it grows (or the data grows), you're much better off creating a data warehouse using conventional DBMS (SQL Server).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list.files` with argument `recursive = True` and `full.names = TRUE` to get file path of all 80 txt files, And then use `lapply` or `for` with `read.table` to read all the files in one `list` which has 80 element, the use `do.call(rbind,your_list)` to combine the list to one data frame.

```
filename<-list.files(folder_path,recursive = T,pattern = ".txt",full.names = T)
all_file<-lapply(filename,read.table)
df<-do.call(rbind,all_file)
```

Comment: Thanks! Gives me an idea, but the problem is I want a data frame for each file since files 0-9 are different tables.

Comment: Then just skip the `do.call` part.

Comment: I edited the original post to make it more clear what I'm trying to do.